# What is a good drawing library or -tool to generate Visio-/UML-like diagramms for the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml, drawing, visio

We need to build dynamically generated Visio- or UML-like diagramms for on a website. We use C# (.Net 3.5 Framework). We have all kind of entities which are related to eachother. One entity can have multiple relations with other entities (0...n). So I will have many blocks and many lines between those blocks and it has to be readable.

What library or tool can be used to generate diagramms for this kind of data?

Output can be Silverlight, HTML5, Flash, SVG or just an Image.

What are your ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[yUML](http://yuml.me/) or [any of these textual modeling tools](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#textual) would be a great choice

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is popular for generating diagrams automatically using e.g. [UML](http://www.umlgraph.org/), see also related discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531420/structured-design-software-to-draw-structure-charts/3600351#3600351).

Answer (score 0):

I use gliffy.com. I don't think it has UML though it does a very good Visio impression.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to generate them programatically? Do users need to interact with them?

If so, you might want to consider drawing the graph with JS Code. Raphael is a good JS Vector Graphics Library.

http://raphaeljs.com/

Also, this SO question has some more links:

[Vector graphics in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410146/vector-graphics-in-javascript)

Comment: I need to generate them programatically, yes. I'll take a look at Raphael JS. Thx!